# Queue of byte arrays in Java

Tags: java, android, queue

I have a problem in my android project.
I have queue, defined as

```
static private BlockingQueue<byte[]> rawQueue=new LinkedBlockingQueue<byte[]>(10000);
```

And I have code that retrieves new byte array and puts it into queue

```
byte[] BulkBuffer=new byte[16384];
for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
    int res=conn.bulkTransfer(endpoint, BulkBuffer, 0x4000, 0);
    if(res>0){
        PacketQueue.add(BulkBuffer);
    }
}
```

The questions are:

1) The byte array is passed to queue by value or by reference?

2) If it is passed by reference does it mean, that after modification of BulkBuffer the queue element will be also modified?

3) If it is passed by reference how can I prevent modification of queue element?

Comment: 1) by ref 2) yes 3) create new byte array(but this will lead to OOMException after some number of iteration ...)

Comment: @Selvin thanks a lot!

Is this code is valid?
`code`
rawQueue.offer(Arrays.copyOf(BulkBuffer, 16384))

Comment: it should works but better use some kind of array pooling